# evaluate $\lim_{x \to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{x}-5x^{-2}+3x^{-3})^{x}$

Tags: calculus

> $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{x}-5x^{-2}+3x^{-3}\right)^{x}$$

I know that the answer is $e$ but how I can formally write the way as I can not use the fact that the limit of a sum is the sum of the limit as this is incorrect:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x-\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{5x^{2}}\right)^{x}+\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{3x^{3}}\right)^{x}$$

Comment: Indeed, what you wrote at the end is highly incorrect..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice, let $\frac{1}{x}=t$, hence $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{5}{x^2}+\frac{3}{x^3}\right)^x=\lim_{t\to 0}\left(1+t-5t^2+3t^3\right)^{1/t}$$

$$=\exp\lim_{t\to 0}\ln\left(1+t-5t^2+3t^3\right)^{1/t}$$
$$=\exp\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1}{t}\ln\left(1+t-5t^2+3t^3\right)$$

Applying L'Hospital's rule for $\frac{0}{0}$ form 
$$=\exp\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\frac{d}{dt}\ln\left(1+t-5t^2+3t^3\right)}{\frac{d}{dt}(t)}$$
$$=\exp\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{\left(1+t-5t^2+3t^3\right)}(1-10t+9t^2)}{1}$$
$$=\exp\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\left(1-10t+9t^2\right)}{(1+t-5t^2+3t^3)}$$

$$=\exp\left(\frac{1+0}{1+0}\right)=\color{red}{e}$$

Comment: in the second move to the end, why did you flip the numerator  and denominator?

Answer (score 3):

Take $\log$ ans use a well-known equivalence:
$$
\log\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}-5x^{-2}+3x^{-3}\right)^x =
\lim_{x\to \infty}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x}-5x^{-2}+3x^{-3}\right)^x =
$$
$$
= \lim_{x\to \infty}x\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x}-5x^{-2}+3x^{-3}\right) =
\lim_{x\to \infty}x\left(\frac{1}{x}-5x^{-2}+3x^{-3}\right) = \cdots
$$

Comment: not well-known for e :(

Comment: where did the log went in the last move?

Comment: @gbox, if $f(x)\to 0$ then $\log(1+f(x))/f(x)\to 1$ (the well-known equivalence).

Answer (score 1):

$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)^n=e.
$$

---

More explicitely, for each $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $x_0=x_0(\varepsilon)$ s.t. 
$$
1+\frac{1-\varepsilon}{x}\le 1+\frac{1}{x}+o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \le 1+\frac{1+\varepsilon}{x}
$$
whenever $x \ge x_0$. It follows that
$$
e^{1-\varepsilon} \le \lim_x\left(1+\frac{1}{x}+o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)^x\le e^{1+\varepsilon}.
$$
The claim follows by the arbitrariness of $\varepsilon$.

Comment: is there more explicit way?

Comment: Yes, I add it in a few (even if it is equivalent)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do this:

Let $\lim_{x \to \infty} (1 + \frac{1}{x} - 5x^{-2} + 3x^{-3})^x = L$.
Then 
\begin{align*}
\ln L &= \lim_{x \to \infty} x \ln(1 + \frac{1}{x} - 5x^{-2} + 3x^{-3})\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(1+x-5x^2+3x^3)}{x} \\
&= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-10x+9x^2}{1+x-5x^2+3x^3} \quad \text{by l'hopital}\\
&= 1
\end{align*}

Therefore $L = e$.

Comment: Can you please explain the second step where you divide by x?

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{5}{x^2}+\frac{3}{x^4}\right)^x=$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\exp\left(\ln\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{5}{x^2}+\frac{3}{x^4}\right)^x\right)\right)=$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\exp\left(x\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{5}{x^2}+\frac{3}{x^4}\right)\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}x\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{5}{x^2}+\frac{3}{x^4}\right)\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{5}{x^2}+\frac{3}{x^4}\right)}{\frac{1}{x}}\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{5}{x^2}+\frac{3}{x^4}\right)\right)}{
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x(x^3-10x^2+12)}{x^4+x^3-5x^2+3}\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1-\frac{10}{x}+\frac{12}{x^3}}{1+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{5}{x^2}+\frac{3}{x^4}}\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(\frac{1-0+0}{1+0-0+0}\right)=\exp\left(\frac{1}{1}\right)=\exp(1)=e^1=e$$

Answer (score 1):

When you have a complicated limit of the form $f(x)^{g(x)}$ it's always better to compute the limit of the (natural) logarithm, so
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}x\log(1+x^{-1}-5x^{-2}+3x^{-3})=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\log(1+t-5t^2+3t^3)}{t}
$$
This is the derivative at $0$ of the function
$$
f(t)=\log(1+t-5t^2+3t^3)
$$
Now
$$
f'(t)=\frac{1-10t+9t^2}{1+t-5t^2+3t^3},
\qquad
f'(0)=1
$$
Therefore your original limit is
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}(1+x^{-1}-5x^{-2}+3x^{-3})^x=\exp(1)=e
$$

Without using explicitly the derivative, you can use the fact that
$$
\log(1+u)=u+o(u)
$$
so
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\log(1+t-5t^2+3t^3)}{t}=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{t-5t^2+3t^3+o(t-5t^2+3t^3)}{t}=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{t+o(t)}{t}=1
$$

Comment: I can evaluate the limit of the power because $e$ is continuous?

Comment: @gbox Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: can I say that all the fractions goes to 0 as X goes to infinity and therefore we have 1 to the power of infinity?

Comment: @gbox Yes, it's a $1^\infty$ form; but I always advise taking the logarithm, in cases like this, which makes it in the $\infty\cdot 0$ form. You have to remember less indeterminate forms, just the base four: $\infty-\infty$, $0/0$, $\infty/\infty$ and $0\cdot\infty$.

Comment: I went over it once more, why "This is the derivative at 0 of the function", and why $f'(0)=1$?
Thanks

Comment: @gbox Write the definition of derivative at zero of that function and you'll see exactly the limit you're trying to compute. The derivative is $f'(t)=\frac{1-10t+9t^2}{1+t-5t^2+3t^3}$ using the chain rule and $f'(0)=1$.

Comment: sorry, the definition of derivative at zero of which function?

Comment: @gbox $f(t)=\log(1+t-5t^2+3t^3)$ as written.

Comment: thank got mixed with the definition of derivative at $x$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{x}-5x^{-2}+3x^{-3})^x$$
as $x \to \infty$ , $y \to 0$
therefore $x=\frac{1}{y}$

substituting 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}(1+y-5y^2+3y^3)^\frac{1}{y}$$
$$\log L=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log (1+y-5y^2+3y^3)}{y} $$
apply LH rule
$$\log L =\frac{\frac{1-10y+9y^2}{1+y-5y^2+3y^3}}{1}$$
$$\log L=1$$
$$L=e^1$$
hence proved

Comment: i solved the problem, and posted it but i saw that some one had already posted the answer above. Sorry if it is the same. please do not down vote it please